# Array value not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
    /*mysql table admin
    id=1, user_name = mike
    id=2, user_name = sam*/

    $user_name_query = mysql_query("select id, user_name from admin");
    $user_name_array = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($user_name_query)) {
        $user_name_array[] = array('user' => $row['user_name']);
    }
    foreach($user_name_array as $key => $record){
        $record_values .= "{$record['user']},";
    }
    $record_values = substr($record_values, 0, -1);
    // $record_values is: mike,sam

    $userThatHaveThePermission = array($record_values); 
    if (in_array(mike, $userThatHaveThePermission)){
echo "do something"
}
```

my question is about the values of variable **$record_values** this variable not working in: $userThatHaveThePermission = array($record_values);
If I add the user names(mike,sam) to $userThatHaveThePermission = array(**mike,sam**); everything working fine, WHY? did I miss something.

Comment: Why are you complicating it so much? Just add the values to the `$record_values` variable in the first loop. If you really must create an array from a string, you need `explode()`.

Comment: For gawds sake, stop using the `mysql_*` API!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are beginner in php-mysql.  I would refactor your code for you.

```
$user_name_query = mysql_query("select id, user_name from admin");
$user_name_array = [];
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($user_name_query)) {
    $user_name_array[] = $row['user_name'];
}

$userThatHaveThePermission = $user_name_array;
if (in_array('mike', $userThatHaveThePermission)){
    echo "do something";
}
```

But take advice of the people commenting on your status. Do not use `mysql_query`. Use some framework.